# I don't comprehend matrixes very well. Does anyone know the output?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    System.out.println(m(matrix, 1));
  }

  public static int m(int matrix, int column) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      sum += matrix[i][column];
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try ?

Comment: It's forbidden code, do *not* execute.

Comment: I need to solve this for my final exam and I got lost along the way with virtual learning. So I am pretty clueless

Comment: Stack overflow is not an online code executor.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: That means Stack Overflow is a forum for (professional) developers who share problems and solutions. It's not for your final exam question that is about interpreting code. Moreover it's not about giving you the solution while you show zero effort solving it yourself.

Comment: Oh I thought it was for students because I always see students use this to solve their questions. But you don't have to be rude about it. I was just asking a question.

Comment: It's not rude, I want to tell you what the matter is very clearly. It's okay if students ask as well, but this doesn't mean that you are free to just copy paste your homework, not attempting it yourself first.

Comment: Well thank you for letting me know. I did not even have the first clue on how to solve this. I think I might need to retake this class because learning online really got me lost.

Comment: Btw. the output is a compiler error because you pass an `int[][]` to an `int` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 7. Matrix is just a table.
The i is iterating over the rows and the column value, the column..

```
 0  1  2
0{1, 2, 3}, 
1{4, 5, 6}
```